# Javascript function just not working for canvas game

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm creating a canvas game (the concept is a side scrolling endless games). I'm trying to make power-ups so I have a main game JS file along with a powerup.js among others. At the moment I'm concentrating on my invincibility power up. I've created some simple code which in theory should work:

In the powerup.js

```
function powerUpInvincibility() {
    invincible = true;
    //window.setInterval(powerUpInvincibilityReset, this.powerUpTime[0]);
}

function powerUpInvincibilityReset() {
    jet1.invincible = false;
}
```

I set the invincible variable in the main js but they are all linked, I've got code in all the JS files working but even when I call the powerUpInvincibility function in Chrome's Console the variable doesn't change.

I've tried making it a variable for the jet and the powerup but that doesn't work either and I've checked for any spelling mistakes several times.

I'm lost, any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to give us a little more code to properly answer this. My guess is that you're encountering some sort of scoping issue, but without the context of the entire powerup file I'm not sure. Is your powerup.js wrapped in an IIFE? (something like this `(function() {...}());` ) Is the context in which you declare invincible wrapped in an IIFE as well? Is invincible supposed to be a property on jet1, or in the global scope? More context will make it possible to answer this question.

Comment: Just to echo the first comment - it's hard to tell from your code whether you should be using `invincible` or `jet1.invincible`, but in all likelihood you need to be consistent across the two functions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry everyone! The actual problem was that one of my powerUp functions tried to access a this variable when it wasn't a powerUp.prototype function. Thanks for the answers!